# Does the avroserde in hive allow to update or delete records?

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I have a table in hive which is created using `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'`.

Trying to update a record but I receive the following error message:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations. (state=42000,code=10294)
```

It seems that AvroSerDe does not support ACID transaction but I can't find any info about that.

Answer (score 0):

Hive transactions doesn't support Avro file formats as of latest Hive release. And it's currently integrated to work with **only ORC file formats**.

According to Hive documentation *"Only ORC file format is supported in this first release.  The feature has been built such that transactions can be used by any storage format that can determine how updates or deletes apply to base records (basically, that has an explicit or implicit row id), **but so far the integration work has only been done for ORC**."*

You can find more information about Hive transactions [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions)

Comment: Thanks Rick for your quick reply.